# yandex smtp doesnt work on codeigniter(digitalocean+ubuntu+serverpilot)

Tags: codeigniter, email, smtp, yandex

I send email on localhost but doesnt work same settings on server(digitalocean+serverpilot).
php's open ssl support is enabled.

> php get "Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to
>   ssl://smtp.yandex.com.tr:465 (Connection timed out)

codeigniter framework get :

> The following SMTP error was encountered: 110 Connection timed out
>   Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be
>   configured to send mail using this method.

my code is:

```
 $config = Array('protocol' => 'smtp','smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.yandex.com.tr','smtp_port' => 465, 'smtp_user' => 'info@mydomain.com','smtp_pass' => 'mypass','mailtype'  => 'html', 'charset'   => 'utf-8');

$this->load->library('email');
$this->email->initialize($config);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

$this->email->from('info@mydomain.com', 'test.com');
$this->email->to('testing@yandex.com');
$this->email->subject('test');


$this->email->message('test body');
$this->email->send();
 echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

nslookup smtp.yandex.com:

> Server:       2001:4860:4860::8844 Address:   2001:4860:4860::8844#53
>
> Non-authoritative answer: smtp.yandex.com canonical name =
>   smtp.yandex.ru. Name: smtp.yandex.ru Address: 93.158.134.38
>   Name: smtp.yandex.ru Address: 87.250.250.38 Name: smtp.yandex.ru
>   Address: 213.180.204.38 Name: smtp.yandex.ru Address: 213.180.193.38
>   Name: smtp.yandex.ru Address: 77.88.21.38

and telnet request is work.

Answer (score 0):

Your outgoing connection may be blocked by a firewall.

Use tool like `tcptraceroute` to locate the problem.